# How to password protect Hadoop NameNode and JobTracker Web UIs?

Tags: hadoop, password-protection

I'd like to know how to password protect the Hadoop Web UIs running on ports 50030, 50070, etc.

Comment: Did you find any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best is to just shut the ports in the firewall and let the users connect with a SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hadoop version 2.7.x, below are the configuration,

**Configuration**
The following properties should be in the **core-site.xml** of all the nodes in the cluster.

**hadoop.http.filter.initializers**: add to this property the org.apache.hadoop.security.AuthenticationFilterInitializer initializer class.

**hadoop.http.authentication.type**: Defines authentication used for the HTTP web-consoles. The supported values are: simple | kerberos | #AUTHENTICATION_HANDLER_CLASSNAME#. The dfeault value is simple.

**hadoop.http.authentication.token.validity**: Indicates how long (in seconds) an authentication token is valid before it has to be renewed. The default value is 36000.

**hadoop.http.authentication.signature.secret.file**: The signature secret file for signing the authentication tokens. The same secret should be used for all nodes in the cluster, JobTracker, NameNode, DataNode and TastTracker. The default value is $user.home/hadoop-http-auth-signature-secret. IMPORTANT: This file should be readable only by the Unix user running the daemons.

**hadoop.http.authentication.cookie.domain**: The domain to use for the HTTP cookie that stores the authentication token. In order to authentiation to work correctly across all nodes in the cluster the domain must be correctly set. There is no default value, the HTTP cookie will not have a domain working only with the hostname issuing the HTTP cookie.